# Facebook auth dialog configuration

Tags: facebook, dialog, authentication

I am trying to provide login using facebook option to my website users. So, I created one Facebook app and using javascript API to integrate. When I click on login button, I get Facebook oAuth dialog. As per screenshots in Facebook, request permissions should have following options with Allow & Disallow buttons:

- Access to basic information
- Extended permissions we set

But, for me, I get a request permissions screen with Login button and when I click on Login button, I get another request permissions screen with extended permissions which has Allow/Disallow buttons. I want to have both these permissions captured in one screen. Can someone please suggest why I am getting Login button and how to avoid it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the *Enhanced Auth Dialog* option under the app's advanced settings is enabled. I suggest you adapted to the new dialog.